# How to run a program in a new PID namespace

Tags: linux, pid, namespaces

How to run a program in a new PID namespace? All tutorials on the internet show writing some custom C code in order to do it. Is there a command instead for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `unshare` program. Note that due to the way pid namespacing works you need to tell unshare to fork too. You may also want to get it to remount proc for you as well (which is possible in newer versions of the `unshare` command I believe).

Comment: Trying on Ubuntu 14.04, I don't see any options related to PID namespaces, only mount, uts, ipc and net.

Comment: Tried now on Centos 7, it has pid. But is giving 'fork: Cannot allocate memory' error. How to tell unshare to fork?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `unshare -fp program`. This will fork the new program and put it inside the new PID namespace.